Web USB / Serial API + led strip KAA332-LH
I wonder if anyone has any experience with the Web USB and controlling a LED strip. I have a basic LED strip. I can connect the device from the browser js, but when I try to do device.open() I'm getting error:
DOMException: Failed to execute 'open' on 'USBDevice': Access denied.
Funnily enough, when I try to use the Web Serial API, I can open the port and getInfo(). I'm also trying to send some data, but I have no clue what payload to add to simply switch off/on the leds...
Ideally I'd like to stick to Web USB API... any idea how to overcome the Access denied problem?
manufacturerName: "Prolific Technology Inc."
productId: 9123
productName: "KAA332-LH"
serialNumber: "KAA332LH2207"
vendorId: 1659



Are you trying to do this in a secure context?

Is the device WebUSB compatible?

Yes, running on https if that's what you mean by secure context.
The device is detected and I can successfully use navigator.usb.requestDevice(), but device.open() is failing

The device presents a serial interface, so the Web Serial API is potentially the correct way to access it. Prolific Technologies is a manufacturer of many USB to serial converter chips.
Do you have any documentation for this device or existing software for it? It's going to be difficult to figure out what commands you need to send it simply by guessing.
It is possible that this device was designed with the assumption that you would be using the GPIO capability present in some Prolific Technologies chips. In that case you will need to configure your system to allow the browser to take control over the device directly (at the USB layer) rather than by utilizing the USB serial driver. On Windows this can be done with Zadig.

As you mentioned, I used Zadig to replace the driver (I should've mentioned I'm on Windows) and now the device.open() method is working! I tried the method also on Mac and on ChromeOS - and they had no problem with device.open() to begin with.

I have no documentation for the device... and yes it's already proving to be quite impossible to guess the commands... Do you have any examples of "common" commands for usb devices?

I assume this device came with some software. Where did you get it from? Who was the manufacturer? If you can get the software running on your computer you can use Wireshark to capture the USB traffic and reverse engineer the protocol.

I ended up using Zadig to replace the driver of the device and that allowed me to use the open() method instantly.
I also manged to get my hands on the spec and a list of commands for the device. There is no chance I'd work them out just by guessing... but now everything is working great.
Thank you @Reilly for the guidance!
